# Use ArcPy to identify annotation reference scale

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, annotation, reference-scale

I would like to retrieve the value of an annotation feature class reference scale using ArcPy (with ArcMap 10.1).

I cannot find where this property is stored (tried to access using the describe object, but it doesn't seem to be there).

The aim is an ArcPy-batched run of the "Append Annotation Tool". This tool holds the Reference Scale as one of the required parameters.

- For one class, I can look it up (in the source class properties)
- For many classes, I would rather batch the process with ArcPy i.e. Provide all annotations as input classes, and read the value of that reference scale for each of them, then reuse this value as a parameter in the Append process. The reference scale is easily accessed in programming, so I was hoping it is accessible one way or another via ArcPy.

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that this is stored as a property.  Are you able to provide more information about why you are looking for it?  It may be that there is an alternative workflow available.

Comment: The aim is a ArcPy-batched run of the "Append Annotation Tool".  This tool holds the Reference Scale as one of the required parameters.
-For one class, I can look it up (in the source class properties) 
-For many classes, I would rather batch the process with ArcPy: Provide all annotations as input classes, and read the value of that reference scale for each of them, then reuse this value as a parameter in the Append process. 
The reference scale is easily accessed in programming, so I was hoping it is accessible one way or another via ArcPy.... 
What do you think?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'll really like to ask those people who have voted to close, what exactly do you find unclear? If there is something that you think is unclear, ask for more details in the comments; Don't just blindly vote to close. And definitely don't vote to close, if you know nothing about what the OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Helene - can you now edit your question so a much improved version results - @DevdattaTengshe perhaps we can discuss closure suggestion as a means to improve questions over in Meta

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I just added some food for thought in Meta [**here**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/are-we-closing-questions-too-quickly)